How should I email HR after an unpleasant / annoying interview?
I just had an unpleasant technical interview today. After presenting myself, the interviewer asked precisely nothing technical, no "test your knowledge", no coding questions, nothing about my projects that are listed on my resume, and nothing related to the JD. They jumped straight towards my one-year delayed graduation from my current master's program, my master thesis (which I emphasized twice that it's not the direction / field that I want to pursue in the future), whether I'm ready to graduate on time, how I would approach this in retrospect, and even how many students have delayed graduation from my lab. They asked most of these in an interrogative / negative tone. I felt annoyed and offended after the interview, though I did not reveal my feelings to the reviewer.
This is by far the worst interview I've attended, and I'm planning a polite email to the HR with this interviewer on the CC list (their recruitment system shows these contact info to candidates). I currently have lines like these in my draft:

Dear HR of Example company,
I hope this message finds you well. This is a response to the interview that I took at 12:34 PM today. The entire interview deviated from the technical part and I was interrogated too much on irrelevant topics. (More details here)
Based on today's experience, I'm afraid I can't be a good match for your company. I hereby request to withdraw my application and I hope you can find your best candidate soon.
Best regards,
iBug

Is there a better (more professional) way to draft this email or react to the situation?
Other notes:

I have sought help from RL friends afterwards and I think I have mentally recovered.
Based on similar reports from my friends, I am going to personally blacklist this company.
I will graduate from my master's program next year and enter the workforce fresh.


Writing this email is likely to get you on the "do not hire" list of that company. This may not matter to you right now but it may come back to bite you later. There is zero benefit for you here. Let it go.

What do you hope to gain by this? 1. You'll probably ruin any chance of ever working there. 2. They're likely to completely ignore you. My advice... let it go and move on.

This interview may not have been what you've expected, but I don't agree with your assessment that the recruiter was at fault. You have a "weak spot" in your resume, and the recruiter did his job: identified that spot and grilled you about it. That won't be the last time that's gonna happen to you. Top priority: practice answers to those questions.

"I'm planning a polite email" Your e-mail draft does not sound polite to me. If you do want to work for them, write the e-mail in a humble way. If you don't want to work for them, then let it go as other users say here.

BTW, I am not sure if this company is in China. If it is, your experience is normal. Chinese tend to pay attention to the master's degree. The degree makes a big difference. In the US or some other places, the degree does not matter as long as you have the skills the company wants. So, you need to specify the location to get the answers that truly answer your question.

Could you expand on what you felt was "offensive" about these questions. "Annoying" and "not relevant" make perfect sense, but (to me) nothing you've described was "offensive"?

I note that in this question you've told a story about a bad experience, and asked for advice on what to do but you never said what your goal was. It's hard to give advice on how to achieve a goal when the goal is unstated. What do you intend to achieve by sending this email?

@EricLippert It could be as simple as "What's the most professional way to approach this?" Or stated clearly, "have the situation resolved in the best way in general sense."

@iBug It's still completely unclear what you want to achieve by e-mailing them. What does "approach this" mean? What do you feel needs to be "resolved" about the situation? Do you think they might offer you a job and want to make it clear beforehand that you won't accept the offer? If you think they're no longer considering you as a candidate, the interview process is over, so why take further action?

You are assuming that the interview was to hire or not hire you and you are assuming that there is a job. What if the post has already been filled and HR just has to interview N people to justify its existence? What if they are just probing the market? https://old.reddit.com/r/recruitinghell/comments/1fbhap7/secrets_of_corporate_hr_departments/

As other answers have indicated, you should probably just let it go. Sending an email regarding your negative experience sounds like unprofessional complaining, and nothing good is likely to come out of it.
Based only on the details in your question, I think you potentially have a distorted view of what a technical interview entails.

the interviewer asked precisely nothing technical, no "test your knowledge", no coding questions, nothing about my projects that are listed on my resume, and nothing related to the JD.

You seem to be under the impression that technical interviews are focused on knowledge or other demonstrations of skills. At my organization, the technical interview is focused on the candidate as a person and potential teammate. We're screening for things like:

Technical knowledge and critical thinking.
Teamwork and related soft skills.
Flexibility to learn new skills and take on new responsibilities.
Adaptability to deal with changes.
Likelihood of being a stable, long-term employee.

As you can see, "coding questions" represent only a portion of what we're trying to find in a candidate. Those "irrelevant" questions that stressed you out are in fact very useful in determining if a candidate is likely to be someone who can grow into whatever role the company needs in the future. I encourage you to prepare yourself for all sorts of questions aimed at getting to know you as a person in interviews, technical or otherwise.

I think your list is missing "ability to take feedback constructively". One of the best practice I've seen for developer interviews is to code-review a piece of code written by the interviewee, challenging their solution. If the interviewee gets all defensive about their code, that's a red flag: once hired, their code is going to get criticized. A lot.

Yep that's another good skill. The list above is not exhaustive, of course, and if you squint at the flexibility to learn new skills bullet, it's kinda there. The main focus of this answer being that there are a lot of non-technical things to learn in a technical interview.

Thank you for the insight. This is the most refreshing answer among those "bad interviews happen and let's move on" ones.

@Matthieu M.
Please explain the mechanism why their code is going to get criticized depending on their reaction to feedback

If you get hyper defensive over a weak point in your CV that's a huge red flag, are you going to be the kind of guy who always want to do things his way and never takes on board any feedback?  I bet if OP had a good answer to the first question re his delayed graduation the interviewer would have moved on instead OP kept digging a hole for himself.

I would add: let it go for your own sake. Learning to let this kind of "it was annoying, but it's in the past and doesn't affect me anymore unless I let it" stuff is a great life skill. Take this as an opportunity to practice it!

@noname7619 Once hired, their code is going to get criticized regardless of their reaction to feedback. The point of screening for this in the interview is to hire people that will later react to inevitable criticism in a professional and constructive manner, learn from their mistakes and see criticism as a valuable opportunity to improve. In contrast to that, candidates who get defensive, arrogant or offended by criticism are likely not the best addition to a team.

@MatthieuM. "is to code-review a piece of code written by the interviewee" - we are also doing the exact opposite. We give applicants (intentionally sub-par) code to review and look for a constructive review from their side.

@Fildor: Yeah, that's a good one too, as it allows judging how they formulate feedback :)

The better way to react is not to waste time on it.
Bad interviews happen. Shrug and move on to the next interview. Remember that you are interviewing the company as much as they are interviewing you, and if the interview is unpleasant that may tell you something about working there... But if you can get to the next layer and it's better, the first can be ignored.
Complaining about it will not do you any good, and will probably not help the company even if they agree with your perception.
Meanwhile, work on developing a thicker skin. Even with a bad interviewer, your goal is to pass the interview so that you can be interviewed by the next stage of the process. That may mean that you have to answer questions that you don't think are relevant. Rather than getting annoyed by it, learn to use those as springboards to the things you do want to say about your skills and your interests.
Very few interviewers have proper training. Very few interviewees have proper training either. You can't fix the former but you can fix the latter, and part of that is learning when you need to take some control of the interview and when you should not do so. Part of it is also learning not to get stressed out about an interview that didn't go as you expected it to; instead, develop a plan for how you will handle if it happens again.
If you really want to help them, then after you are hired by that company  and it's clear you are trying to help rather than just complain, discuss with your manager how to get a note to that interviewer (not HR) saying "Thank you for your time. I'm not trying to tell you how to do your job, but here's what confused me during the interview; you weren't asking what I expected (a, b, and c) and were asking other questions (d, e, and f). Did I misunderstand the questions? If not I'd like to understand why you went that direction, in case I'm ever interviewing again." People respond a lot better to positive comments than negative ones. And taking it to HR would be an actively hostile move;  unless the other interview was clearly violating your rights (and putting the company at immediate risk), the highest you normally want to go would be that interviewer's direct manager.

OP should be glad they weren't alive when the stress interview was a common thing.

I would argue that "Even with a bad interviewer, your goal is to pass the interview so that you can be interviewed by the next stage of the process." It conflicts with what is stated in the second period.

@shoover Can you elaborate on "when"? And probably "where" maybe, as I suppose this is heavily culture-dependent.

@iBug I've never experienced one personally, but I recall reading about them about 20-30 years ago in the U.S. Wikipedia includes them as a type in its article on job interviews: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_interview#Stress  The interviewer is intentionally hostile to see how you react.

@shoover the first sentence of that section reads "Stress interviews are still in common use."

@JohnMadden Thanks, I've interviewed twice in 25 years, and the most recent was in academia, where that's not really a thing, so I'm not up on what is or is not current in industry interviews.

I have sent polite feedback to recruiters when I felt an interviewer was rude to me. I don't expect it to help me, but there's a non-zero chance that the feedback will get to the interviewer's boss or even trigger some additional training, and help future candidates. One time I was even surprisingly offered a re-do, the (large) employer wanted to make sure they didn't pass on a good candidate because of one fluke bad interview (I still got rejected). I'll only do this when one interviewer is rude; I had an interview where there were two people tag-team insulting me, and I just let it go.

@L.Dutch: Depends on in what way is the interview was bad, I suppose. Yeah, I may revise that; thanks .

Actually I love stress interviews.  It gets me off the hook in actually telling the interviewer anything of value because they only care HOW you react and any fool can learn how to kiss a$$ when someone is mad at them.

@TedMittelstaedt They may have in mind that that is what you are doing...

Revised and extended my answer slightly.

You scotched the interview and I think you know it and would rather blame the interviewer than yourself.
What sunk you is the statement:
"it's not the direction / field that I want to pursue in the future), whether I'm ready to graduate on time,"
The way I'm taking it and likely the way the interviewer took it is, you have not graduated yet and you are applying for full time.  So that means, they are going to hire you and then for the next 6 months, year, 2 years, whatever - your head is going to be focused on this graduate degree you are working on - which in the interview you took pains to say you don't even LIKE or plan on pursuing - instead of what they are paying you to do.
If I was the interviewer, I'd be pissed you are wasting my time and grill the heck out of you.
I'll tell you what I tell my kids:
When you go into a job interview you ALWAYS give the impression (at first) that you have NOTHING ELSE TO DO and are just DYING to work for them and that the pinnacle goal of your life is to secure a job from them - you will do ANYTHING for them - from sweeping up coffee grounds to throwing out your own trash to cleaning the bathroom.
Your goal is to get them so lit up that they found a candidate that will work for peanuts and walk on water that they make an offer right then and there.
You adopt this attitude up until the SECOND that they start talking compensation - and then you go for the jugular.   "Oh SURE you want me to be the low man on the totem pole and make the coffee?  No problem I'll do that for you.  But, ya know, I have this super high rent and a wife and a sick mother all needing money so I just can't swing that job for under $190k a year.  I know you understand"
Let them destroy their misconceptions that you are a stupid desperate fool once you start talking money.  And, if they DO hire you for $190k and expect you to clean the bathroom - then GREAT.  Just tell your boss "Hey, for the hour I'm going to take to clean the bathroom/make the coffee I calculated that you will be paying me approx $200 - and so instead of me doing that I'm just going to hire a maid to do it and pay her $60 an hour and go out fishing - and pocket the difference"
That will get the "let's haze the new guy" attitude out the door quicker than grapes through a goose and get you the respect you deserve.  But all that has to happen AFTER they hire you.
A job interview is the LAST place you want to talk about your goals, plans, dreams, and what the heck you plan to do in your off time.  If you get asked those questions that is a surefire understanding that you have an interviewer who knows less about interviewing than would fit in a thimble and if you know what you are doing you can manipulate the heck out of them.  But your answers to THOSE kind of questions should ALWAYS be cribbed off the company website.  So the company website says "Our goal is to help customers work and integrate new technologies" and in a job interview the interviewer asks "so what do you like doing after work"  (or a question along those lines designed to elicit that response) then your  answer SHOULD NOT BE "Oh I like to go to my local BDSM club" it needs to be "On my off time I like to read technical journals about new technologies" and make sure to mention some titles that you might have seen in a dentist's office or library.
A GOOD interviewer's job is to extract every bit of info about you they can.  I've done it the nasty way and I've done it the nice way.  The nice way gets you lots more info.  The nice way is a lunch meeting.  I do that for anyone who is going to be paid 6 figures or above.  It gets them relaxed and they start slipping up so I learn more.  And if they don't slip up then I'm even more impressed with them.  But if I perceive that they are "job shopping" or otherwise wasting my time - then they don't get the nice way.  They get the way you got.
Remember, a job interview IS NOT the place for you to talk about YOU.  It's the place for you to talk about how much money you can make the company.  We all go to work to make money, son, not to "express our inner child" or whatever rot and rubbish that your fru-fru generation has been taught by the bleeding hearts.  Show them that your goal is to keep your head in your job and not your "dreams" you can think about your dreams on your off time and you don't need to share them with them.  They are just paying you to work, not to be happy.  If you can be happy while working - that's a bonus to you - they really don't give a tinker's damn about that.

Perhaps there's some missing background in your answer. In my location "campus recruitment" targets next-year graduate students and expects candidates to start working in summer the next year, so "finishing up graduate work" is laid out dead plain to anyone. Similarly no one would expect the kind of battle-tested solid experience typical of a 10-year veteran, be it technical or interpersonal. Your answer could certainly apply better elsewhere.

I don't think this approach on interviewing will work well in all cultures.  Particularly not here in Scandinavia.

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Indeed, but OP's question is tagged "China", so if this answer describes how it works in China, it is valuable. Ted, you should clearly state what culture/country your answer is for, to avoid confusing and misleading people from other cultures. For example, it certainly does not apply at all to western/central EU. Around here, such an over-the-top approach would get you raised eyebrows at best, and at worst it would make the interviewers feel you're either a workaholic or hiding something by obviously making stuff up instead of answering honestly.

Some things are not cultural though. If I'm explicitly hiring someone with a formal degree in tech x, I'd be quite suspicious of their attitude if they'd be willing to scrub the toilets rather than to work with what they've been studying. It can only mean something bad: maybe they've been disgracefully fired because of misconduct at their previous work, maybe they have a very problematic private situation indeed, with debts or other troublesome situations that will distract them plenty from focusing on their job.

Also, lying to the employer during an interview or polishing your resume too far isn't going to do you no good in the long run...

My best advise isn't to invest yourself too heavily in each interview you get. It's an easy thing to do: getting a new job is important and possibly life-changing, and so we do tend to prepare and mentally invest in them out of instinct. We remember many of the interviews we've been to for a long time afterwards, good or bad. This is especially true early on in your career when you haven't been to many interviews yet. It's normal then to be extra nervous and/or invested in interviews when you are new to the whole thing.
Think of it like dating, a job interview is like finding a good match and if it obviously isn't going to work for one or both parties, then just leave it at that and move on. There will be no second date. Just like when dating, some interviews might be disasters. Moving on is the key, dwelling on it won't do you any good.
Politely turn the job down and only provide details why in case the employer explicitly asks for it. In which case they might even listen to the feedback.

From the interviewer's perspective:
We may first note that there are lots of bad interviewers out there for sure. Perhaps particularly so in tech - it is not uncommon that someone gets promoted to manager because of their great technical skills and not for their great people skills (which would have been a far more relevant merit).
Now as someone who's hosted a whole lot more interviews than I've been to as a candidate myself, I can relate to the employer's point of view. Interviewing young people fresh out of school is hard, because normally during an interview you would ask about relevant work experience as the single-most important merit. But if the candidate has no such experience in the field they graduated in, school projects and classes tend to become a natural topic.
The interviewer may not have the technical domain knowledge to get down to details. Or they may have a whole lot of domain knowledge, to the point that they regard you as a blank sheet with nice prerequisite skills, but not expecting you to shine in technical details. Most things in technology takes some 10+ years to truly master, after all.
And then there is this: a good interviewer isn't focusing so much on technical details or even your resume, but who you are as a person. Between the lines it might be important for them to figure out how good you are at working independently, how quickly you learn, how you work in a group etc etc. So they might not actually care the slightest if you used technology x for purpose y in your school project, but rather that you did all of it yourself with minimal input from your teacher, or whatever else they think is relevant for the position.
Having unexplained gaps in your resume is a major red flag for any interviewer, so be prepared to answer such if present.
Similarly, if you haven't actually graduated formally, it usually means that you end up in a lower salary category, so this needs to be established for the employer to know which salary to offer if they hire you. Particularly true if you apply for a job hosted by the government/state rather than a private company.
Now of course they can and should ask these things in a respectful tone - again with the dating analogy: you can't realistically hope to charm your date if you are interrogating them or treat them as suspicious. Similarly, they should be prepared to answer your questions asked in a similar respectful tone.
If an interview is completely one-sided and only focusing on the candidate's merits and not about what the candidate is looking for or how they might fit in with the company or the team you'll be working with, then the interview isn't very good and I'd be wary as a candidate.
Some small things that are positive signs that they do care about how you will fit in: is there's a second interviewer present from the actual department/team hiring, are they giving you a quick tour (at least to the coffee machine?), do they let you briefly meet the staff you'll be working with or the office you'll be sitting in, do they share some rough outline over what work procedures or technologies they are using. And so on.

Assuming that your intention is to withdraw from the interview process, the polite and professional way is to write something à la:

Thank you for the interview. I have decided to pursue other opportunities.

That is all. They did not ask for your feedback on their interview process, so you don't give it. Move on.

Do you want to work for the company?

Yes. Reconsider once more. The HR is not Hiring/Recruiting department, it deals with all legal interactions that fit Human Resources. Do you believe this attitude is specific to recritment? I don't think so.

No. It's not your problem they have repelling HR staff. Remember the name(s) and keep them in your "do not want to work for" list. Live your life as happy as you can.


Remember, there is not Just One Company To Work For. There are more. And the hiring process is not that you are being chosen as an apple in a basket. You are choosing too.
This interaction was unpleasant. So what. Look elsewhere.
Send the email only and only if someone else (typically the HR head or CEO) asks you why you declined their offer / interrupted the hiring process in the middle.
If you really want to contact them on your own, you can inform them you are no more intersted. That's all.
You know, when other candidate is chosen, very few HRs botehr to inform the rest too. Or they do in automated fashion. You are not obliged at all to act differently.

I'm... kinda bothered that the consensus here seems to be "let it go" or "it can come back to bite you".
This appears to me the kind of attitude that perpetuates a sheep's mentality in the job market. Some people need to be educated, and that includes companies; and if we want to see some change in the world, we must sometimes take it upon ourselves to steer things in the right direction.
You've so far been discouraged from writing back to them, so I'm going to offer a different take - one that validates your intended action and improves upon the execution. And I assure you, this is something I would absolutely do. So, here it is:

To: Example company's Human Resources team
Good [morning|afternoon|evening],
I hope this message finds you well.
With respect to the interview that I took with your company at [date],
I would like to offer some feedback, which I hope is taken
constructively. While this is not something I would normally do, I
believe the circumstances call for it, for the reasons outlined below.
I'm afraid the interview experience has left much to be desired. To
put in clearer terms, it has been, by far, the worst I ever took part in over my [x] years-long career.
[Include relevant remarks here - but keep it short and simple!]
I would like to hereby withdraw my application to the job position,
and I hope my feedback is taken into consideration for future
interviews with other applicants.
Regards,
iBug

Compared to your version, this one:

Specifies the interview date, instead of the time (because that comes off as "weird" IMO);
Introduces the motivation behind the email (feedback)
Makes it very clear that the experience was rather terrible;
Wishes no luck to them finding "a good candidate", because you don't seem to really wish them luck and don't have to go out of your way to appear extra friendly - especially given the circumstances here, when this could come across as "fake" (I'm missing a better word) or somewhat contradictory, as the intent of your email is to criticize;
Replaces "best regards" by "regards" for the same reason of extra friendliness.

The above is just a suggestion, of course - one that I wrote in one go just now for the sake of example. Adapt at will.

Having thick skin is required for life. The interview described is by no means offensive, nor tough, the author does seem capable of taking constructive criticism very well. Sending an email won’t result in the company hiring the author.

@Donald That was not exactly the impression I was left with by reading the question as is, but I guess we can't say for sure. My answer is intended to be generalizable though. And, as for your last remark, I agree, but then again neither should it. That's not the point.

This kind of bridge burning may not work well, especially not in the long run, where people may remember you from earlier.

It is easy to advise other people to "not be sheep" when you don't have to bear the consequences of their actions.

OP has not even graduated yet, so their X years long career has X close or equal to zero. People don't typically enjoy it when a complete newbie comes in and starts telling them how badly wrong they're doing their jobs. And personally,I don't see anything particularly offensive or annoying about the questions OP was asked, so I would say OP might be overreacting, although this is definitely a cultural thing.

While I might agree that some people need to be educated, my concern is that the OP is not experienced enough to know whether it's the interviewer, or they themselves, that need it.
